# Changing the mouse pointer to be like the default blender Rotate pointer?

Tags: python, add-on, operator

I was looking into bpy.context.window.cursor_set() because I want my modal add-on to have the same cursor that you get when rotating stuff in blender, but it seems that the parameters for curusor_set don't include these kinds of arrows. Nor could I find a setting to change the orientation of the mouse pointer graphic as I rotate something. There is also a dotted line when you use blender's default rotate, that goes from the mouse pointer to the rotation pivot. I'd also like to implement that.

Does anyone know how to achieve something like that? Instead window.cursor_set(), should I be looking more at custom bgl stuff?

[image]